# generate a PDF containing R output inside latex table

Tags: r

I wrote a script that generates 4 variables from 2 for loops, each one of them contain a big number of data. I want to place these variables inside a data frame and then create a latex table so I can output it as a PDF.

```
t <- read.table("data.txt", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
uni <- unique(c(t$V9))

testresult <- function(column, datacol) {    
  if(column=="PP") {
    for (xp in uni) { 
      for(yp in uni) {
        testx <- subset(t, V9==xp)
        testy <- subset(t, V9==yp)
        zz <- wilcox.test(testx[[datacol]],jitter(testy[[datacol]]))
        p.value <- zz$p.value
      }
    }
  } 
}
```

I want the table to contain these 4 columns (xp, yp, p-value, significance) for each xp and yp in the 2 for loops.

The question about whether the jitter in my function is appropriate has been taken to stats.stackexchange.com:
[is it wrong to jitter before performing wilcox test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9201/is-it-wrong-to-jitter-before-performing-wilcox-test)

Comment: Is this a pairwise Wilcoxon test?  If so, check out `pairwise.wilcox.test`.

Comment: @Aaron: hello , i already made the test and i have the result , but how can i put them inside a data frame and then generate a latex table from this data frame and output it as PDF??

Comment: I'll trust that this is appropriate for your case, but it seems very odd to jitter a variable before running a statistical test on it.  Also, without the jitter, your function simply recreates the pairwise wilcoxon test that's built into R.

Comment: concerning the jitter , i'm using it because if i didn't all the p-values will be the same value equal to 1. i read this in a tutorial , it can avoid ties. is this will give wrong result??

Comment: @weblover You're better off asking directly on http://stats.stackexchange.com/. I don't know about your sample size, but there may exist better alternatives like permutation tests, depending on your specific question. Also, your R function looks unnecessarily complicated. We can help for the tex/pdf output too, but I feel you should get back here with the stats response, as your original question belongs on here. (Be kind enough to cross-link the two threads.)

Comment: @chl: thansk for your response , but how can i cross-link the 2 thread??

Comment: @weblover Just add a link on stats.SE to this question, and back link here. These are Markdown-enabled websites, so put something like `[generating PDFcontain R output inside latex table](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15013/generating-pdfcontain-r-output-inside-latex-table)` in your post to get a working hyperlink.

Comment: ok , thnx , and after getting result from stats we will continue this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a data frame with your results, use `rbind` to add the results by row to an output object within the loop, as shown with the `out` object below.

To get a LaTeX table from the data frame, use `xtable`.

The easiest way to make all this happen is with an Sweave document, like the following.  If you don't want to use Sweave, you can just run the R code and copy/paste the resulting LaTeX tables into your own LaTeX document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
<<echo=FALSE, results=hide>>=
# make up some data
set.seed(5)
N <- 15
t <- data.frame(a=round(runif(N)*100), 
                b=round(runif(N)*100),
                V9=rep(LETTERS[1:3],N/3), 
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
uni <-  unique(c(t$V9))

# function to get result for a particular data column
testresult<- function(column, datacol) {    
  out <- NULL
  if(column=="PP") {
    for (xp in uni) { 
      for(yp in uni) {
        testx <- subset(t, V9==xp)
        testy <- subset(t, V9==yp)
        zz <- wilcox.test(testx[[datacol]],jitter(testy[[datacol]]))
        out <- rbind(out, data.frame(xp=xp, yp=yp, p.value=zz$p.value))
      }
    }
  } 
  out
}

# get results for columns a and b
ta <- testresult("PP","a")
tb <- testresult("PP","b")

# load xtable library for output
library(xtable)
@ 

\section*{a results}
<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
print(xtable(ta), include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE)
@ 

\section*{b results}
<<results=tex, echo=FALSE>>=
print(xtable(tb), include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE)
@ 

\end{document}
```

If you'd rather not Sweave, you could do something like what the `latex` function of `Hmisc` does and create the .tex file from within R and then do a system call to pdflatex.  Here's a function that would do that on a table `tab`, outputting the results to a file with basename `file`.

```
pdfit <- function(tab, file) {
  texfile <- paste(file, ".tex", sep="")
  cat("\\documentclass{article}\n\\begin{document}\n", file=texfile)
  print(xtable(tab), include.rownames=FALSE, floating=FALSE, 
        file=texfile, append=TRUE)
  cat("\\end{document}\n", file=texfile, append=TRUE)
  sys(paste("pdflatex", texfile))
}
pdfit(ta, "ta")
```

Comment: @Aaron : thnx a lot for your help, but i don't want to use sweave , i just want to output the latex table generated for ta and tb in a PDF file. what should i add in this case?? and how to control the lines separating variables of the table inside R??

Comment: I don't understand your question; if you don't want to use Sweave, just run the R code in R and copy/paste, as I said.  If I misunderstood your question, please rephrase.

Comment: @Aaron: this is just 1 PDF file , i can copy the output and place it inside latex , but i have another case that will generate around 25 PDF , i can't copy and paste :S , soo is there a case to integrate latex with R as i wanted ?? (to automatically generate PDF from latex tables inside the for loop) , thanks in advance

Comment: I'd make one pdf file and then split it with pdftk; something like `pdftk largepdfile.pdf burst`.

Comment: You also might want to look at the `latex` function in the `Hmisc` package; I think it will just make dvi files but you could do something similarly to make pdfs.  I'll add a note to my answer too.

Answer (score 1):

If you can save the table to a text file, I think you can import it in LaTeX with the pgfplotstable package. From its documentation:

> PgfplotsTable is a lightweight sub-package of pgfplots which employs its table input methods and the number formatting techniques to convert tab-separated tables into tabulars.
>
> Its input is a text file containing space separated rows, possibly starting with column names. Its output is a LaTeX tabular which contains selected columns of the text table, rounded to the desired precision, printed in the desired number format (fixed point, integer, scientific etc.).